# PacketReceiver for multithreaded NetworkMonitor project

Tags: c++

I'm developing a toy project for monitoring some network parameters. Now I'm implementing a feature that will allow to measure a packet round trip between hosts by measuring time between TCP SYNC and TCP SYNC/ACK. One of the options for feeding this application with packets will be setting up capture on network device. I implemented class 'PacketReceiver' which responsibility is:

- Listening on given network interface
- Dispatch packets for subscribed observers

Aim of the project is to learn by making mistakes and getting feedback, so each constructive critique is very welcomed.

My considerations:

- Does the locking on every layer on every packet in `DistributePacket` function could/should be done better?
- `DistributePacket` function iterates over every layer of packet and does find by protocol and then iterates over every observer. It will probably impact performance. How it could be optimized?
- Is interface of the class appropriate? Maybe something should be decoupled according to best practices?
- Is the code readable? Is there anything that could make it more readable?
- Is there something that could be improved in terms of best programming practices?

PacketReceiver.cpp

```
#include <PcapLiveDevice.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include "PacketReceiver.h"
#include "TcpLayer.h"

void PacketReceiver::OnPacketArrived(pcpp::RawPacket* pPacket, pcpp::PcapLiveDevice* pDevice, void* userCookie){
    auto packet = std::make_shared<pcpp::Packet>(pPacket);
    auto packetReceiver = static_cast<PacketReceiver*>(userCookie);

    packetReceiver->m_packetQueue.Enqueue(std::move(packet));
}

bool PacketReceiver::StartCapturing() {
    auto& devices = pcpp::PcapLiveDeviceList::getInstance();
    auto deviceList = devices.getPcapLiveDevicesList();

    pcpp::PcapLiveDevice* wlp7s0 = devices.getPcapLiveDeviceByName(m_captureName);
    if(!wlp7s0){
        std::cout << "Device: wlp7s0 was not found." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if(!wlp7s0->open()){
        std::cout << "Device wlp7s0 could not be opened." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if(!wlp7s0->startCapture(OnPacketArrived, this)){
        std::cout << "Unable to start capturing." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

bool PacketReceiver::AddFilter(PacketObserverShPtr observer, const pcpp::ProtocolType protocol) noexcept{

    auto attachedObserver = m_packetObservers.find(observer);
    if(attachedObserver==m_packetObservers.end()) {
        return false;
    }

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        auto subscribedObservers = m_protocolToObserver[protocol];
        subscribedObservers.insert(observer);
    }

    return true;
}

bool PacketReceiver::RemoveFilter(PacketObserverShPtr observer, const pcpp::ProtocolType protocol)  noexcept{
    auto attachedObserver = m_packetObservers.find(observer);
    if(attachedObserver==m_packetObservers.end()) {
        return false;
    }

    auto subscribedObservers = m_protocolToObserver.find(protocol);
    if(subscribedObservers==m_protocolToObserver.end()) {
        return false;
    }

    auto protocolObserver = subscribedObservers->second.find(observer);
    if(protocolObserver!=subscribedObservers->second.end()){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        subscribedObservers->second.erase(protocolObserver);
    }

    return true;
}

bool PacketReceiver::Attach(PacketObserverShPtr observer) noexcept{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

    auto result = m_packetObservers.insert(observer);
    if(!result.second)
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool PacketReceiver::Detach(PacketObserverShPtr observer) noexcept{
    auto searchResult = m_packetObservers.find(observer);
    if(searchResult==m_packetObservers.end()) {
        return  false;
    }

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        m_packetObservers.erase(searchResult);
        for(auto& protocol: m_protocolToObserver){
            protocol.second.erase(observer);
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void PacketReceiver::MainLoop() {
    while(m_runThread){
        auto packet = m_packetQueue.Dequeue();
        DistributePacket(std::move(packet));
    }
}

void PacketReceiver::OnThreadStarting() {
    StartCapturing();
}

void PacketReceiver::DistributePacket(std::shared_ptr<pcpp::Packet> packet) {
for(auto currentLayer = packet->getFirstLayer(); currentLayer!=NULL; currentLayer=packet->getFirstLayer()){
    auto protocol = currentLayer->getProtocol();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    auto observers = m_protocolToObserver.find(protocol);
    if(observers!=m_protocolToObserver.end()){
        for(auto& observer : observers->second){
            observer->Update(std::move(packet));
        }
    }
}
}

PacketReceiver::PacketReceiver(const std::string &captureName) : m_captureName(captureName) {

}
```

PacketReceiver.hpp

```
#pragma  once

#include <PcapLiveDeviceList.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include "PacketQueue.h"
#include "Thread.h"
#include "Interfaces.h"

class PacketReceiver : public Thread {
public:
    PacketReceiver(const std::string& captureName);

    using PacketObserverShPtr = std::shared_ptr<IObserver<std::shared_ptr<pcpp::Packet> > >;

    bool Attach(PacketObserverShPtr observer) noexcept;
    bool Detach(PacketObserverShPtr observer) noexcept;

    bool AddFilter(PacketObserverShPtr observer, const pcpp::ProtocolType protocol) noexcept;
    bool RemoveFilter(PacketObserverShPtr observer, const pcpp::ProtocolType protocol) noexcept;
private:
    void MainLoop() override;
    void OnThreadStarting() override;

    bool StartCapturing();
    static void OnPacketArrived(pcpp::RawPacket* pPacket, pcpp::PcapLiveDevice* pDevice, void* userCookie);
    void DistributePacket(std::shared_ptr<pcpp::Packet> packet);

    PacketQueue m_packetQueue;
    std::set<PacketObserverShPtr > m_packetObservers;
    std::map<pcpp::ProtocolType, std::set<PacketObserverShPtr> > m_protocolToObserver;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::string m_captureName;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give you some tips related to packet processing:

- Have mutex/lock for every read packet is a bad idea in terms of performance
- Copy packets form one place to another is also a bad idea, you should move packets or keep reference the same part, take into consideration that memory copy operations are expensive for a packet application like yours.

In general your code is readable and is clear what you want to achieve, I will suggest you to use a profiler in order to find the bottlenecks.